# Unlocking external disks upon login

Tags: macos, security, encryption

AFAIk, FileVault 2 on OS X automatically unlocks/decrypts the startup disk on login. Could external disks/partitions be unlocked on login? If not FV2, are there other ways, e.g., scripts? Scripts would need to read from the keystore - right?

Thanks